# Password Protection of PDF Files

Tags: java, pdf, adobe, password-protection

We have a requirement to protect PDF files using a password. Are there any Java-based, open source tools which will help us in this regard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using the [iText](http://itextpdf.com/index.php) java PDF library.

Inside iText, there is a class called [PdfEncrypter](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfEncryptor.html) which should let you password protect a PDF file.

Comment: I am unable to access this link and it seems to be down for quite some time

Comment: If you're having trouble accessing the main iText website, you can also download the code from sourceforge:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/

Answer (score 4):

You can easily make the Password protected pdf file in java......to do so you will require two addtional jar/lib bctsp-jdk16-1.46.jar and bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar along with the itextpdf-5.2.1.jar.
Download all jars from here [Download Jars](http://education.youngindiablog.in/)

Also below is the snippet of the code

```
private static String USER_PASSWORD = "password";
private static String OWNER_PASSWORD = "naveen";
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Document document = new Document();
      try
      {

         PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("E:\\HelloWorld.pdf"));
         writer.setEncryption(USER_PASSWORD.getBytes(),OWNER_PASSWORD.getBytes(), PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING,PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
         document.open();
         document.add(new Paragraph("This is Password Protected PDF document."));
         document.close();
         writer.close();
      } catch (DocumentException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with [iText PDF](http://itextpdf.com/) for java:

some examples:

http://1t3xt.info/examples/browse/?page=example&id=42

Comment: iTextSharp is the .NET version :) I think you meant iText itextpdf.com :)

Answer (score 0):

FOP library also allows encryption:

http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.94/pdfencryption.html

Comment: Is that for existing PDF's or the one you are currently creating?

Comment: The example in the link is for the file that you are currently creating, and I think it works on other existing PDF's. Joshua didn't mention in what context he needs encryption.