# How to protect an already existing PDF with a password?

Tags: java, itext

How to set password for an existing PDF?

Comment: Please always provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. In addition, describe what you already tried. Which language are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Password Protection of PDF Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032380/password-protection-of-pdf-files)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you look at the [EncryptionPdf](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=219) example in chapter 12 of my book?

It's as simple as this:

```
public void encryptPdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    stamper.setEncryption(USER, OWNER,
        PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 | PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

Note that `USER` and `OWNER` are of type `byte[]`. You have different options for the permissions (look for constants starting with `ALLOW_`) and you can choose from different encryption algorithms.

As for the parameters: `src` is the path to the existing PDF. `dest` is the path of the encrypted PDF. It should be obvious that you can not write to a file while you are reading it. That is explained here: [How to update a PDF without creating a new PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16081831/using-itextsharp-stamper-required-to-update-in-the-same-pdf)

Comment: how do u encrypt a pdf if only you have the byte array as input - and need another byte array as output, it is posible?

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña, giving an answer to your question and referring to Bruno's answer too.

Comment: throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/spongycastle/crypto/engines/AESFastEngine;

Comment: Strangely, Chrome seems to display the PDFs created with this code without asking for the password. Firefox and the Preview-App in MacOS ask for it.

Comment: My previous comment is probably related to the fact that I use iText 2.1.7. When using this call the encryption worked stamper.setEncryption(userPassword.getBytes(), ownerPassword.getBytes(), PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);

Answer (score 0):

Answer for @Alberto Question: How do u encrypt a pdf if only you have the byte array as input - and need another byte array as output, Used the previous answer.

I have a method called addPassword(byte[] templateByte) which accepts byte array of PDF file as a parameter and returns the encrypted byte array as a response.

```
public byte[] addPassword(byte[] templateByte)
    {

        String USER_PASS = "Hello123";
        String OWNER_PASS = "Deva123";
        PdfReader pdfReader = null;

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream(templateByte.length);

//removed manual write to output stream

        try
        {

            pdfReader = new PdfReader(templateByte);
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, byteArrayOutputStream);
            stamper.setEncryption(USER_PASS.getBytes(), OWNER_PASS.getBytes(),
                    PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING,
                    PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 | PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA);
            stamper.close();
            pdfReader.close();

            return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }
```

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream?

Comment: @Lijo, please complete your question. I did not get it.

Comment: This did not work for me, I still can open my PDF without password prompt.